# Disallow copy/paste in QTableView in pyside

Tags: python, qt, pyside, copy-paste, qtableview

I have `QTableView` that gets information from a `QSqlQueryModel` and displays it in real time. The thing is, `QTableView` allows the user to copy and paste the info from one of the fields.

```
    projectModel = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()
    projectModel.setQuery("select * from queue",self.db)
    self.total_rows = projectModel.rowCount()
    projectModel.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'ID cola')
    projectModel.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Código')

    self.projectView = QtGui.QTableView()
    self.projectView.setModel(projectModel)
    self.projectView.resizeColumnsToContents()
    self.projectView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
```

How do I deny copying the content of QTableView and pasting it outside in a text editor, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the whole table read-only like this:

```
    self.projectView.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
```

**EDIT**:

If you also want to prevent copying of cells, you will need to kill the relevant keyboard shortcuts. Below is some example code that does that:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.table = QtGui.QTableView(self)
        model =  QtGui.QStandardItemModel(rows, columns, self.table)
        for row in range(rows):
            for column in range(columns):
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem('(%d, %d)' % (row, column))
                model.setItem(row, column, item)
        self.table.setModel(model)
        self.table.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.table.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (source is self.table and
            event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress and
            event == QtGui.QKeySequence.Copy):
            return True
        return super(Window, self).eventFilter(source, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window(5, 5)
    window.setGeometry(600, 300, 600, 250)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I can still copy the cell contents. Tried putting it before and after setting the model and I can still copy and paste the cell contents.

Comment: @LeandroPoblet. How are you copying and pasting? I just tested with a `QTableView` and `QStandardItemModel`, and I couldn't find any way to do it (with or without setting the edit triggers). There's no context menu or keyboard shortcuts for copy or paste (except when editing), so I don't understand how you are doing it.

Comment: I'm just doing Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V, nothing out of the ordinary. There's no context menu like you said, but the default copy and paste shortcuts do allow me to do so.

Comment: @LeandroPoblet. I cannot reproduce that. I've added a test case to my answer, and there are no copy and paste shortcuts. Please test my example and confirm (it might also be useful to say what platform you are on).

Comment: Same thing, I'll try to test this in my local windows machine and see if It's an actual PySide issue.

Comment: @LeandroPoblet. Same as what? And I'm testing on Linux, not Windows. Also, I see exactly the same behaviour with pyqt (i.e. no shortcuts).

Comment: @LeandroPoblet. Actually, the copy shortcuts (Ctrl+C and Ctrl + Insert) **do** work for me - it's just the paste that's missing. I had a look at the source code for `QAbstractItemView.keyPressEvent`, and sure enough, there's handling for copy, but not paste. The only way I can paste is if the cells are editable.

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear enough, I'm sorry if I wasn't. Like you said, you can copy cells but can't **paste inside the cell**, but what I'm talking about is copying a cell and paste it **outside**, for example, in a text editor or an email. This is what I'm trying to avoid. I'll update my question with this explanation.

Comment: @LeandroPoblet. I've updated my answer with a solution.

Comment: Perfect! Sorry for not being clear enough with my request.